# makeBinnedCountsFile function error in R 3.4.1

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04

While running my codes in my system (Ubuntu 16.04 & r 3.4) it shows ***could not find function "makeBinnedCountsFile"***,and also i cant load the package RAPIDR,which shows installation of package **‘RAPIDR’ had non-zero exit** status.
This is the code what i enter,

`makeBinnedCountsFile(bam.file.listc("COC818_005.bam","COC819_006.bam"),`

`sampleIDs = c("COC818_005", "COC819_006"),`

`binned.counts.fname = output.fname,`

`k = 20000, mask)`

Comment: What is the actual error message when you try to install `RAPIDR`?

Comment: Error in readRDS(file) : 
  cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 3.6.0; need R 3.5.0 or newer
Installing package into ‘/home/ngslab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘GenomicAlignments’ is not available                                            Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RAPIDR’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: The error tells us that the installation of `GenomicAlignments` (a dependency for RAPIDR) could not be installed. What is the output of install.packages("GenomicAlignments")? And are you trying to install from source? It would be probably best if you upgrade your R version to the latest (3.6.2 (2019-12-12))

Comment: when i install GenomicAligmnt package,it shows 'Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘GenomicAlignments’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)'...I already tried the above makebinnedcountfiles function in 3.6 version. but i cant run that code,thats why i downgrade to a previous version

Comment: Then I'd suggest you rather fix the code so it runs with the latest R version than trying to fix old packages. But if you can't or won't do that you'll have to find old versions for the packages in question. But I'd really advise against that solution!

Comment: Just to be clear: You won't be able to install the lates version of `RAPIDR` as long as you don't upgrade `R`.

Comment: Now i just upgrade to latest version,and  i tried to install package genomicallignment and now shows    "install.packages("GenomicAlignments")
Installing package into ‘/home/ngslab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘GenomicAlignments’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)"

Comment: I've never used that package, but a simple google search brings  [this](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicAlignments.html) up.